# Why am i getting an error on my program when writing a line containing the help syntax?

Tags: python, image

i am currently writing a program in python to highlight differences between two images. When I try to run the code it says there is a syntax error on the line help="firstinputimage" If someone could tell me what is wrong it would be great (code is below)

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-f, "--first, required=True
                help="firstinputimage")
ap.add_argument("-s", "--second", required=True
                help="second")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

imageA = cv2.imread(args["first"])
imageB = cv2.imread(args["second"])


grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True)
Diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM: {}".format(score))

thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

for c in cnts:



    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(imageA, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(imageB, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow("Original", imageA)
cv2.imshow("Modified", imageB)
cv2.imshow("Diff", diff)
cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Change both your `required=True` into `required=True,`.

Comment: You forgot the comma on the previous line.

Comment: You should always copy paste the full error message because it may contains some useful info to help you.